# GitHub - how to clone a repository into multiple repositories and push each to GitHub

Tags: git, github

My task is to clone a [repository](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) on GitHub to multiple repositories locally.

All the repositories should have the same codebase as the old repository that was cloned. Then I will be able to make code changes to each repository and push each of them to an individual repository on GitHub.

[App 1](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example-app1)

[App 2](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example-app2)

[App 3](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example-app3)

I was able to clone the old repository to multiple repositories pushed onto GitHub as above. But how can update each of the cloned repositories with the changes made to the old one?

Comment: You would just set the `upstream` branch for all those repositories to be the same as the one you cloned from I believe.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is multiple branches, not multiple repositories.

Comment: What is your goal? This sounds like something you don't actually want to do

Comment: I need to deploy each of them to Heroku as individual applications. On Heroku deployment page, it requires URL to the repository. All applications should have the same/identical codes as the origin repository with app-specific changes made to individual apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing. As the comments say, it sounds like you want branches, not repositories, if this is all for yourself. If there is some reason you're trying to fork your code and they need to be different repositories, the default remote for any push/pull operation is `origin`. By default, `origin` points to the remote that it was cloned from, but there's nothing special about it and it can be changed with the `git remote` command.

For instance:

```
git clone https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example parse-server-example1
cd parse-server-example1
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example1
(repeat for 2 and 3)
```

Would achieve what you're asking. If there's already different forks, you can make remotes with other names and be explicit in "git push" about what remote/branch you want to push to.

For instance:

```
cd parse-server-example1
git remote add example2 https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example2
git push example2 master
(repeat for as many different repos/names as you want, ie.)
git remote add example1 https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example1
```

would push your (local) example1 code to the example2 fork and (after the above)

```
git fetch example2
git checkout example2/master
(do stuff, maybe commit)
git checkout example1/master
```

would switch between the different forks locally. This is generally a better way to work, unless there's a reason you need multiple copies cloned into different directories at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @driusan! I actually did the your first part of the commands as above to clone the old repo and add example1, example2 and example3 as new origin repositories. The question is, if the old repo is updated, how can the example1, example2 and example3 repos get updated accordingly as they have been essentially disconnected from the old repo.

Comment: I guess I need new repositories rather than branches for my purpose. The potential example1, example2 and example 3 apps should be independent to each other.

Comment: They're only disconnected if you don't set up remotes pointing to them. That's the point of setting up remotes with names other than `origin`. `git fetch origin` (assuming haven't changed origin), followed by `git push examplen (branchname you want to push to)`, after doing the second part is essentially what you're asking for. It's why it's a better idea to use remotes instead of different checkouts with different origins.

Comment: Thanks @driusan. Do you agree with my answer as below by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to driusan's answer, I think my answer to the question is:
Clone the upstream repo: [OLD_REPO_URL](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) to new repositories on my own account on GitHub:

```
https://github.com/{MY_ACCOUNT}/parse-server-example-APP1
https://github.com/{MY_ACCOUNT}/parse-server-example-APP2
https://github.com/{MY_ACCOUNT}/parse-server-example-APP3
```

by the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example parse-server-example-APP1
cd parse-server-example-APP1
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/{MY_ACCOUNT}/parse-server-example-APP1
(repeat for 2 and 3)
```

Now that new repositories have been created, I can work each of them and make changes to the code. Push code changes back to origin when it's done.

If the OLD_REPO has been updated, run the following commands to fetch and merge updates with the cloned repos:

```
cd parse-server-example-APP1
git remote add upstream https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push
```